# Group objects with values as array of index

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an output in the format

```
[{"name":"ABC",
"type":123
},
{"name":"ABC",
"type":111
},
{"name":"ABC",
"type":1432
},
{"name":"XYZ",
    "type":523
},
{"name":"XYZ",
    "type":52
}];
```

I am trying to create a grouping object with index positions of array

Sample output:

```
{
"ABC":[0,1,2],
"XYZ":[3,4]
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your code as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group it by `name` and push the index.

```js
var array = [{ name: "ABC", type: 123 }, { name: "ABC", type: 111 }, { name: "ABC", type: 1432 }, { name: "XYZ", type: 523 }, { name: "XYZ", type: 52 }], 
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        (r[a.name] = r[a.name] || []).push(i);
        return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is the difference between `Object.create(null)` or simply `{}` ? Is it better in this case ?

Comment: it depends on the use, if you expect to have keys like prototypes `toString`, for example, the an really empty object would help, because then it is iterabel over the own keys.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var array = [{
    "name": "ABC",
    "type": 123
  },
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "type": 111
  },
  {
    "name": "ABC",
    "type": 1432
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "type": 523
  },
  {
    "name": "XYZ",
    "type": 52
  }
];

var groups = array.reduce((o,a,i)=>{
  o[a.name]=o[a.name]||[];
  o[a.name].push(i);
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

In a one-liner you will have

```
var groups = array.reduce((o,a,i)=>(o[a.name]=o[a.name]||[],o[a.name].push(i),o),{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go :

```
var newObj=[];
var digitArray=[];
var myObj=[{"name":"ABC",
"type":123
},
{"name":"ABC",
"type":111
},
{"name":"ABC",
"type":1432
},
{"name":"XYZ",
"type":523
},
{"name":"XYZ",
"type":52
}];
for (var i=0; i<=myObj.length-1; i++){
    digitArray = (""+myObj[i].type).split("");
    newObj[myObj[i].name]=digitArray;
}
console.log(newObj);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jd9rdgg/

Comment: I was looking for an answer using lodash, map or reduce. More of a learning excerise, so accepting the other answer.